# How to extract <title> from html and add a new line <h1> with that text in the body over multiple html files?

Tags: html, regex, converters

I have a bunch of legacy html files where the the title is only stored in `<title>` metadata. I need to add a line in body with the metadata `<title>` as an `<h1>`. For example, extract what's in the `<title>{COPY-THIS}</title>` from the title and then add a new line at the beginning of the body with `<h1>{COPY-THIS}</h1>`.

I think I need to use a regex to find what's in the title but not really sure how to do the bulk manipulation or even what code might work best for this conversion.

I'm on Mac or Linux. What is a method to copy what's in the title of each file and add a new line in bulk?

Comment: Regex is not the proper tool to use. Use an HTML parser. Here, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Strictly speaking Jorge is correct, but you might get away with this approach https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78625/using-sed-to-find-and-replace-complex-string-preferrably-with-regex

Comment: Ok. Interesting points. I guess what I had in mind was using regex to extract or copy what's in the title tag and then find and replace the initial <body> tag with something like <body><h1>title-extracted</h1>. So what you guys recommend is using an html parser instead? So maybe my question should be how to parse html to extract text from title and add additional html markup at the top of the body?